# How to filter records with the same column value with angularjs?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have the below table

```
    Name  |  DeviceName  |  TabName  |  OnText  |  OffText
    GENER    Gener           Gener       Stop       TEST
    GENER    Gener           Gener       Start      TEST
    ATS      ATS             ATS         Open       CB1
    ATS      ATS             ATS         Close      CB1
    ATS      ATS             ATS         Open       CB2
    ATS      ATS             ATS         Close      CB2
    ATS      ATS             ATS         Start      Gener
    ATS      ATS             ATS         Stop       Gener
```

I took this table with AngularJS and Node.js in variable `$scope.controls`.
And know I want to push in a new table with records that do not have the same `OffText` value.

I want to create below table:

```
Name  |  DeviceName  |  TabName  |  OnText  |  OffText
GENER    Gener           Gener       Stop       TEST
ATS      ATS             ATS         Open       CB1
ATS      ATS             ATS         Open       CB2
ATS      ATS             ATS         Start      Gener
```

I want to do this with AngularJS.

Answer (score 3):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.controls = [
    {Name:'Name2', OffText:'1'},
    {Name:'Name3', OffText:'2'},
    {Name:'Name1', OffText:'1'},    
    {Name:'Name5', OffText:'2'},
    {Name:'Name6', OffText:'3'},
    {Name:'Name7', OffText:'4'},
    {Name:'Name4', OffText:'2'}    
  ]
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<table ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>    
      <th>OffText</th>
    </tr>  
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat='item in temp = (controls | orderBy : "OffText" | orderBy : "Name")' ng-if='$first || item.OffText != temp[$index - 1].OffText'>
      <td>{{item.Name}}</td>    
      <td>{{item.OffText}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks very useful, but my records maybe not order by OffText. I tried to do with function _.each() in controller

Comment: Should you strictly preserve order? If not, you can do it only at HTML, without javascript at all.